# Анимация textbox'а при валидации вводимых данных в textbox с помощью INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox

Как сделать валидацию данных вводимых в `texbox` в `VM` с помощью `INotifyDataErrorInfo` с анимацией `textbox`'a?
Если `textbox` будет пустым, то его `background` должен сразу стать красного цвета и в течении 2 сек. плавно окраситься в прежний цвет. Валидация должна происходить по нажатию кнопки. На данный момент, когда `textbox` пустой и я нажимаю кнопку, то `background` `textbox`'а становится красным через `Trigger.EnterActions`, но как `background` с красного цвета плавно окрасить в прежний цвет через `Trigger.ExitActions`(ведь нужно через какое то время делать `ErrorsChanged?.Invoke`, когда `HasErrors = false`) я не знаю.

VM:

```
 public class LoginPageViewModel :  BaseViewModel, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        public LoginPageViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
        {
            MainViewModel = mainViewModel;

            GoCommand = new RelayCommand(CheckCredentials);
        }
        public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

        public ICommand GoCommand { get; }

        private string text;
        public string Text
        { 
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                SetField(ref text, value);
            }
        }

        public bool HasErrors { get; set; } = false;

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || (!HasErrors))
                return null;
            return new List<string>() { "Invalid credentials." };
        }
        public void CheckCredentials(object obj)
        {
             if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)) HasErrors = true;
             else { HasErrors = false; }
             if (HasErrors)
             {
                 ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("Text"));
             }
        }
    }
```

Шаблон `textbox`'а:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxMain" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFD3D9DE"/>
        <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="6,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Gray" x:Name="placeholder" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Panel.ZIndex="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="placeholder" To=".65" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="placeholder" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="placeholder" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="border"  From="Transparent" To="#19FF0000" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornerPlaceholder"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: А без анимации и кастомных стилей, я так понимаю, все работает?

Comment: Да, даже с анимацией кое-какой работает, просто нужно как на сайте vk.com. Попробуйте ничего не вводить в поля авторизации и нажмите войти.  Фон текстбокса сразу окраситься в красный и в течении небольшого промежутка времени окраситься обратно.

Comment: Так добавьте еще один `ColorAnimation` в `StoryBoard`, который будет анимировать цвет назад. Получается, этот вопрос не про валидацию данных, а про анимацию, тогда назовите его соответствующим образом.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Триггер в шаблоне:

```
  <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Duration="0:0:2">
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="border" From="Transparent" To="#19FF0000" Duration="0:0:0.0"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="border" BeginTime="0:0:1" From="#19FF0000" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
```

Метод валидации в VM:

```
public void CheckCredentials(object obj)
        {
             ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("Text"));
             if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)) HasErrors = true;
             else { HasErrors = false; }
             if (HasErrors)
             {
                 ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("Text"));
                 HasErrors = false;
             }
        }
```

[image: Textbox]